# How to put html code inside a html file?

Tags: html

I am building a simple html tutorial for my university . But I am not able to put the examples within the html file ! I tried `<code></code>` but it did not worked ! I searched google but no help from there .

Comment: You need to encode your delimiters: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/VdFpt/

Comment: Do you mean how do you stop your HTML code being rendered by the browser and actually show the markup? Example: you want to display `<b>This is bold text</b>` instead of **This is bold text**. Is that right?

Comment: @sje <pre></pre> did not worked !

Comment: @Jared I need to write delimiters manually ?

Comment: And with `PRE` and a full `HTML` document: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/VdFpt/1/

Comment: Not necessarily; for instance, in PHP you could use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: @Jared 'htmlspecialchars()' is working...but it will write the example in one line :(

Comment: See here, which also includes the PHP code for display. Not sure what you're doing, unless you are not wrapping in a `PRE` tag. http://jfcoder.com/test/htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to HTML escape any HTML special characters.
To conserve the indentation, you should wrap it in `<pre>` tags.
To format it as code visually, you should also wrap it in `<code>` tags.
The results looks like this:

```
<pre><code>
&lt;p&gt;
   This is an example of
   &lt;strong&gt;HTML&lt;/strong&gt;.
&lt;/p&gt;
</code></pre>
```

This is rendered as:

```
<p>
   This is an example of
   <strong>HTML</strong>.
</p>
```

Comment: This is the correct way. @Suraj, there are tools on the internet to help you quickly escape special characters such as this one: http://www.felgall.com/htmlt47.htm

Comment: What is the benefit of using `CODE` like that?

Comment: Thank you very much mwan100....I was wondering how I could write long examples :) You two solved my question . Thanks

Comment: @Jared It's simply the semantic markup for code. By default it means browsers display in a monospaced font.

Comment: I thought that PRE's did that as well in most (all?) browsers, but I guess I'm not sure. I can see the semantic argument.

Comment: @Jared That's actually true, whether it makes sense is another story. :) The W3C recommends the `<pre><code>` format: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-pre-element. It does make it easier for your own stylesheets if you have elements that should be pre-formatted but not monospaced.